# Laravel Failed to authenticate on SMTP

Tags: laravel, sendgrid

when I am trying to send an email with sendgrid I have got this error. How can I solve it?

```
Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "dfadsfasdf" using 2 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response. Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 250 but got an empty response.
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't also login to sendgrid using 2FA

Comment: I already solve it.  Create a sender identity as well as you have to verify. @samu

Comment: how do I create a sender identity? @salman